# fire base is retrieving null values

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

i am working on a web app that uses fire base
here is my  java script code :

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCuG09M2Z10h-sVz3n0tu-lzcNzspiZM5o",
    authDomain: "actfirebase.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://actfirebase.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "actfirebase",
    storageBucket: "actfirebase.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1024677586041"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("news");

rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

var name = snap.child("news1").val();
var name2 = snap.child("news2").val();

document.getElementById("fnews").innerHTML = name;


});



</script>
```

and her is the html

```
<section class="news" id="news" style="opacity:0.01;">
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">Latest news</h3>
        <article id="newses">

            <h2 id="fnews">this is the standers text.!!!</h2>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div id="news21" class="info" style=" text-align:center; width:98%;" >
                <h4 Style="color:#ffffff;">Omnis iste natus error </h4>
                <p id="news22" style="color:#000066" >Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores (...)</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <h4 style="color:#ffffff; text-align:center; "><a href="#" style="color:#ffffff;">ARCHIVED NEWS</a></h4>


    <!-- / container -->
</section>
```

my problem is that when i launch the app  the text changes from this is the standers text.!!! to NULL

i don't know what the problem is please help me

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with a "child_added" listener?  What is the contents of your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you are listening to the wrong event?

try changing:

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
```

to

```
rootRef.on("value", snap => {
```

and the child `news1` will load in just fine.

If you wanted to only load data when new children are added to your Firebase, then you would have to not directly access a child of that reference. This is because child_added is only ever fired once any child meaning it has no children that were previously added only the new one.

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

var name = snap.val(); // <--- omit the .child()

...
```

Comment: thanks for your help. it worked just fine but can you please explain to me the difference between them?  because i tried adding new children but it also didn't work.

Comment: the definition in the firebase docs it quite good: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added